# Expectation of $(X+Y+Z)^3$

Tags: probability

Given that X,Y and Z are independent random variables and we are also given the moment generating functions of X,Y and Z, is there an easy way to find the expectation of $(X+Y+Z)^3$? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $X,Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables, so:

$E(X+Y+Z)^3=E(X^3+Y^3+Z^3+3(X+Y)(Y+Z)(X+Z))$

$= E(X^3+Y^3+Z^3+3X^2Y + 3X^2Z + 3XY^2 + 3Y^2Z + 3XZ^2 + 3YZ^2 + 6XYZ)$

$= E(X^3)+E(Y^3)+E(Z^3)+E(3X^2Y) + E(3X^2Z) + E(3XY^2) + E(3Y^2Z) + E(3XZ^2) + E(3YZ^2) + E(6XYZ)$

$= E(X^3)+E(Y^3)+E(Z^3)+3E(X^2)E(Y) + 3E(X^2)E(Z) + 3E(X)E(Y^2) + 3E(Y^2)E(Z) + 3E(X)E(Z^2) + 3E(Y)E(Z^2) + 6E(X)E(Y)E(Z)$

Answer (score 1):

Use linearity of expectation and the fact that all powers $X^a$, $Y^b$ and $Z^c$ are also mutually independent so $$\mathbb{E}(X^aY^bZ^c)=\mathbb{E}(X^a)\mathbb{E}(Y^b)\mathbb{E}(Z^c).$$